# Problem with Ubuntu live different behaviour between computers

Tags: 16.04, live-usb

recently I've built my own live Ubuntu using Systemback (copying my own home folder) and then I burnt it on a USB key.
Now I have a problem that I can't understand.

Booting from one computer (an Acer) the live starts correctly and I can enter into a system that is the same I burnt.

Booting from another computer (a Dell, it's the machine from which I created the ISO) the live starts but it show me only the Guest session with localhost.localdomain

Can some have some hints about this unexpected behaviour?

Thank you

Comment: I would check how you referred to your partitions in the file system table (`/etc/fstab`) to ensure you specified specific partitions (eg. UUID) and not something that may change because of BIOS/UEFI config (eg. /dev/ refs), also as I don't know Systemback, that it didn't do something that creates a problem (eg. duplicate UUID) when booted on the system you created it on.

Comment: Thank you, i'll check it. A strange fact is that i tried the live with another Dell (same laptop as the one I used to create the ISO) with no operating system on it, and the behaviour is the wrong one.